# Remove My Custom MKMapView from UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, mkmapview, swift2

I have created a custom `MKMapView` of size 200x200 on my `UIViewController` to show the path from current location to destination location. It is showing location and path. But now i want to dismiss this `MKMapView` and i want to see my `UIViewController`. 
So i have created a button on the right corner of `MKMapView` but i am not able to remove `MKMapView`. 
I have tried this code below on action of button.

```
func close() {
    mapView!.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

I Have declare map view like this:

```
    var mapView:MKMapView? = MKMapView()
```

then i have called a method showMap() from viewDidLoad() like this:

```
       func showMap() {
    //Setup our Map View
    mapView!.mapType = .Standard
    mapView!.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView!.frame = CGRectMake(topView.frame.origin.x, topView.frame.origin.y, topView.frame.size.width, topView.frame.size.height)
    mapView!.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(mapView!)
}
```

After this i called showCloseButtonForMap() like this:

```
      func showCloseButtonForMap() {
    let mapCrossBtn = UIButton()
    mapCrossBtn.frame = CGRectMake(crossBtn.frame.origin.x+20, crossBtn.frame.origin.y+20, crossBtn.frame.size.width, crossBtn.frame.size.height)
    if let image = UIImage(named: "X@2x.png") {
        mapCrossBtn.setImage(image , forState: .Normal)
    }
    mapCrossBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    mapCrossBtn.addTarget(topView, action: "close", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(mapCrossBtn)
}
```

Here crossBtn is another button which is hidden right now.
Any help will be appreciated.

Error Log:
          Communications error:  { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" =>  { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>

2015-11-19 15:02:27.390 YEWADemo[2328:235956] -[UIView close]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc6d0c32270
2015-11-19 15:02:27.408 YEWADemo[2328:235956] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView close]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc6d0c32270'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107175f45 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108e9cdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010717e56d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070cbeea ___forwarding_** + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070cba98 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000107995e91 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000107b014d8 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000107b017a4 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000107b008d4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000107a03ed1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000107a04c06 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001079b42fa -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010798eabf _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6844
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070a2011 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107097f3c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070973f3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107096e08 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010b993ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010799430d UIApplicationMain + 171
    19  YEWADemo                            0x0000000106c2cdfd main + 109
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010c27a92d start + 1
    21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: How you have add mapView, show your code please

Comment: Did ```close``` function be called?

Comment: yes its called but here is the error log i got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mapCrossBtn` target should be `self`(which usually is current view controller), your `topView` without '`close`' function.
Try to change:

```
  mapCrossBtn.addTarget(topView, action: "close", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

to

```
mapCrossBtn.addTarget(self, action: "close", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: Thats ok its still going in close func but what should i write in close func as mapView!.removeFromSuperview() is not working and giving error.

Comment: mapView!.removeFromSuperview() it works no issue. You just change the button target should works. If any error paste it.